# Escaping special characters in json

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, datatables

I built Data table in mvc this data table in rendering page i send to it 100 rows after that you can get data by AJAX (see more) in rendering i send data in json string

Code in httpget action

```
    viewmodelobj.str= (new System.Text.StringBuilder(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(viewmodelobj.datalist)).Replace("\\r", "<br/>").Replace("\\t", "").Replace("\\\"", "&quot;").Replace("'", "&#39;").Replace("\\\\", "&#92;").Replace("\\n", "<br/>")).ToString();
```

and i need to escape special characters because if i send it without escaping those characters data will not displayed

Code in view

```
var jsobj= JSON.parse(workqueueLoadedData);
        $('#datatableId').DataTable().rows.add(jsobj).draw();
```

But when i make see more and get data by ajax i didn't have to escape special characters although i use  almost the same code 
Send data by ajax

```
var jsonResult = Json(new
        {
            data = lisOfWorkQueue
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;

        return jsonResult;
```

So do you know why it's working right in ajax without escaping special characters unlike get action ?
and is there another way to send json from controller to view in rendering step without escaping special characters , thanks in advance

Comment: I searched a lot about my issue and didn't find good solution so any body here has any idea

Comment: I don't understand why you have to escape your data.  I do what you are doing, I use newtonsoft to serialize my strings and shove  them into a hidden textbox for client side use.

Comment: Oh, wait, why are you not first doing your replaces and then your serilizations?

Comment: I used newtonsoft also but it didn't solve the problem to me and i'll enhance in my code to make replace before serialization but it doesn't my problem now

Comment: what does your data look like?    I would like to see your data mapping between your json object and the datatable, and a little bit of your raw data.